# Spring Boot Activity 6 Rest api and Activity modeler

Tags: java, spring, activiti, bpmn

how to integrate the activiti 6 modeler (explorer) to spring boot. is there any tutorial or any document?

- I would like to create a module (e.g. order mng, to confirm a order) and bind a process to that
- edit or create a new process on activity 6 explorer to design
- at last  deploy the process , at this stage every order use this process

thank you in advance

Comment: If you want that kind of tutorial, you should look for it at udemy because you want bottom to top tutorial.

Comment: thank you for your reply, actually i dont wanna learn java, i want to find a solution to integrate  the activiti 6 modeler to my project! there is no tutorial on udemy about that

Comment: That's because few people are using activiti 6. Hope you can find your own way.

Comment: Up voting the question. Looking for the same thing. It appears the explorer is no longer deployed with version 6

Answer (score 0):

Much of the Activiti-explorer has been moved to the activiti-ui module from version 6. The code for the Activiti App WAR can be found here:

https://github.com/Activiti/Activiti/tree/6.x/modules/activiti-ui/activiti-app

Inside you can see Activiti leverages the Oryx Editor for authoring models. The Orix site is below:

http://oryx-project.org/Oryx

Documentation is here:
https://code.google.com/archive/p/oryx-editor/downloads